# Assignment to constant variable one set null to dueDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting below error after jquery upgrade to 3.6 version

Error :-

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

In the line :-

```
var Item = function () {
  Name = null
  dueDate = null // here in the console showing the error 
  ns = null
};
```

Any idea how to fix this

Comment: declare the dueDate globals as a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: All three vars are now in global scope (because no let, const or var inside the brackets). If you have a const dueDate outside the var Item, then you are trying to re-assign to that const

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like at least one of the variables declared with const.
name,dueDate or ns.
You need to define them with let or you should not re-assign them.

Comment: how can i define them with let or var boz i need to re assign it

Comment: So I presume Name,dueDate and ns are defined somewhere above this code block.Uf thats the case go there define them like this :
    let Name ;
    let dueDate ;
    let ns;
If thats not the case define them inside the function:
const Item = function () {
    let Name = null;
    let dueDate = null; // here in the console showing the error
    let ns = null;
};